# c# visual studio creating window application for searching files and outputting results

Tags: c#, forms, window

I am trying to create the skeleton of my next school assignment but I am having some difficulties.  The goal of this assignment is to create a search text box and 3 radio buttons.  If the search box is empty then selected radio button will display information in a list box regarding that radio button.  If search text box is not empty, then the program will search the files for content containing words and display in list box.  The files provided are sequential text files.

I keep getting a hard crash which doesn't give me a line to fix and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have this code in the button that will be pressed once text box is filled or a radio button selected

```
string gamesData;
string salesData;
string companyData;

StreamReader inFile;

inFile = File.OpenText("game.dat");
inFile = File.OpenText("SalesNumbers.dat");
inFile = File.OpenText("company.dat");

while (!inFile.EndOfStream);

if (searchTxtBox.Text == "")
{
    if (microRb.Checked)
    {

    }
    else if (eaRb.Checked)
    {

    }
    else if (blizzRb.Checked)
    {

    }
}
```

when I try to run this, I click the button and it gives me a hard crash, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? thank you.  (I do have System.IO; in top of the program)

Comment: What do you mean by "hard crash"?  Are you not getting an exception with any details in it?

Comment: That is correct, the application freezes and I have to go into task manager to close it, thanks

Comment: You have an infinite loop.  You need to change your code so that it can finish.

Comment: `while (!inFile.EndOfStream);` won't ever end.  Did you mean to have a `;` there? Add a `{ }` and perform some file operations in order to satisfy the `!inFile.EndOfStream` guard

Comment: sorry I did not mean to have a ; at the end of                                                   while (!inFile.EndOfStream)

Answer (score 0):

Change your while-loop so that it actually does something.
Right now, all its doing its doing is checking the same statement over and over again.

Drop the semicolon from `while (!inFile.EndOfSteam);`
After you do that, it will execute the entire next `if` statement, though I would use braces to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you are using an infinite loop.. `while (!inFile.EndOfStream);` because you are not traversing the stream. You might want to try something like this

```
if(searchTextBox != ""){
    while (!inFile.EndOfStream){
      inFile.read();
    }
}
```